# The Linky in Standard mode does not work like the Linky in History mode

Tags: python

I have a Linky consumption meter in standard mode. I want to read it on the ICT output. I read well in History mode but I don't read it properly in Standard mode. Can you help me.

Have you an example of Python script to read he TIC of my Linky in mode Standard ?
This programme does not work :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try: 
        line = ser.readline().decode('ISO-8859-1')
        print(line)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a repository on github [teleinfo-linky](https://github.com/hleroy/teleinfo-linky/tree/main) which does this.

The code reading the info from the TIC linky is from [line 98](https://github.com/hleroy/teleinfo-linky/blob/dd75a94272861b5188118fa7fd7aa1fae5a20b4a/linky.py#L98). Don't forget to follow the license.

I can't tell if the code works well, I don't test it myself.

Comment: Thank you. The terminal instruction "screen /dev/ttyAMA0 9600,cs7,parenb,-parodd,-cstopb" works correctly, the outputs are consistent. However, I can't read the Linky's ICT using a python program. The example given works well with the Linky in History mode but not in Standard mode.